# Make it so you don't have to hit "Enter" after entering input - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simple way to make it so that Python will read user input without having to click enter after entering it?  I'm working on making a simple cursor with a while loop, and don't want to have to enter every time I hit a key to move the cursor. I am using PyCharm on Windows.

This is what I am currently trying, and nothing happens when I enter a key:

```
 import msvcrt
 running = True
 pos = [0,0]
 while running:
      move = msvcrt.getch()

      if move == "w":
          pos[0] = (pos[0] + 1)
          print(pos)
      elif move == "d":
          pos[1] = (pos[1] + 1)
          print(pos)
      elif move == "x":
          break
```

Comment: What do you mean "move the cursor"?

Comment: For example, I want to be able to push the W key and have the cursor's position (saved as a list: [0,0]) move up, or push S and have it move down.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use the `msvcrt.getch()` method:

```
import msvcrt
char = msvcrt.getch()
```

On UNIX, you can install the [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) package and use the `getch.getch()` method:

```
import getch
char = getch.getch()
```

Comment: I'm using this and nothing is happening:                                             `import msvcrt

running = True

pos = [0,0]

while running:
    move = msvcrt.getch()

    if move == "w":
        pos[0] = (pos[0] + 1)
        print(pos)
    elif move == "d":
        pos[1] = (pos[1] + 1)
        print(pos)
    elif move == "x":
        break`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to paste my code in a comment, keeping the formatting .

Comment: It works if you run it in command line or REPL. It won't work if you run it in an IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: Oh, I'm using PyCharm.  What are my options?

Comment: Please see my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package and use the `keyboard.on_press` method to listen to events of keyboard presses:

```
import keyboard
import time
import sys

def on_press(event):
    global pos
    move = event.name
    if move == "w":
        pos[0] = (pos[0] + 1)
        print(pos)
    elif move == "d":
        pos[1] = (pos[1] + 1)
        print(pos)
    elif move == "x":
        sys.exit()

pos = [0,0]
keyboard.on_press(on_press, suppress=True)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```